# Identify Excel cell is read only

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, excel-addins

I am working on excel addin project and I need to get read-only cells using code. I need to check cell is read only using cell address. I can get active worksheet using following code.

```
 Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Is there a way to check a specific cell is read only?

Answer (score 0):

The `AllowEdit` property of a cell will indicate if a cell is ReadOnly.

Please bear in mind this is a read-only property as well so it cannot be changed.

```
var activeWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet;
var cell = (Excel.Range)activeWorksheet.Cells[0, 0];
bool isReadonly = cell.AllowEdit;
bool isLocked = cell.Locked;
```